# HTTP error: 401 after owncloud upgrade to 9.0.2 using pyocclient

Tags: python-2.7, owncloud

I've been using the owncloud python package for about a month now (https://github.com/owncloud/pyocclient). This is a great package and has been working good for me until recently. I have a fairly simple job the automatically takes daily updated files from a local server and uploads them to my owncloud server. Today, my owncloud desktop client was not working and I was prompted to upgrade to version 9.0.2. I did this and the desktop client works again. However, my file transfer job now fails with a HTTP error: 401. This is all being run on a UNIX server.

I've tried a simple test that also fails:

```
import owncloud

oc = owncloud.Client('https://my/server')

oc.login('user', 'password')
oc.mkdir('testdir')
```

This results in:

```
ResponseError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-271a2b6ab42e> in <module>()
----> 1 oc.mkdir('testdir')

/home/model/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/owncloud/__init__.pyc in mkdir(self, path)
    428         if not path[-1] == '/':
    429             path = path + '/'
--> 430         return self.__make_dav_request('MKCOL', path)
    431
    432     def delete(self, path):

/home/model/software/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/owncloud/__init__.pyc in __make_dav_request(self, method, path, **kwargs)
    618         if res.status_code == 204 or res.status_code == 201:
    619             return True
--> 620         raise ResponseError(res)
    621
    622     def __parse_dav_response(self, res):

ResponseError: HTTP error: 401
```

When I run `oc.put_file` I get the same error. I get no error using my login with `oc.login`. Seems odd that I'm logged in OK, but can't upload files or make a directory. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try add index.php/apps/files/ in oc like oc = owncloud.Client('https://my/server/index.php/apps/files/') for me works :)